# How do I get the dimensions of a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout, preferredsize

I am making a calculator. I used a `GridBagLayout` to arrange the buttons, and so far it looks like this:

[image: normal calculator look]

I am trying to find the exact size of the grid so I can set the size of the `JFrame` to match it. In the [`GridBagLayout` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), I found three methods: `maximumLayoutSize`, `minimumLayoutSize`, and `preferredLayoutSize`. I tried all three and set the `JFrame` to each size to see how they worked:

When I looked at the dimensions returned by `maximumLayoutSize`, they were huge (millions and billions).

When I used the dimensions returned by `minimumLayoutSize`, I got width=151, height=150, which looks like this:

[image]

When I used the dimensions returned by `preferredLayoutSize`, I got width=220, height=180, which looks like this:

[image]

Instead, I want the dimensions of the GridBagLayout when it looks normal like it is in the first picture. How can I get these dimensions?

Comment: Great description (an image paints a thousand words) of a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831). +1

Comment: That was a good read. Thinking back on my previous questions, I've done that a few times now.

Comment: *"I've done that a few times now"*  Me as well.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call, [`JFrame#pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29), it will pack the frame based on the needs of the frame decorations and the preferred size of the frames content.

Comment: Is it okay to leave out frame.setSize(width, height) if I include frame.pack()?

Comment: @mathguy54 Absolutely, you should very rarely need to call `setSize` on a window...

Comment: Should I always use `pack()`? In the past, I've used `setSize()` for all of my windows and added components to different `BorderLayout` regions.

Comment: `pack` is the preferred method.  `setSize` sizes the entire frame to the specified size, that is, the outer edges of the window will be equal to the value you pass `setSize`, which means you are not taking into account the size of the window decorations.  `pack` calculates the preferred size of the content and makes the window large enough to accommodate that AND the window decorations, so the viewable (content) area will always be sized to it's preferred size..